# Calculating total hours of an event in Google Calendar

Tags: google-calendar

I'm looking to see or get a weekly summary of the number of hours per event in a Google Calender.

How can I get these hours totalled up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally I used google apps script over a google spreadsheet, [the code in a github gist](https://gist.github.com/juanpabloaj/4683450) .

```
// add menu
function onOpen() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var menuEntries = [{name:"Calcular Horas", functionName: "calculateHours"}];
ss.addMenu("Hours", menuEntries);
// calcular al iniciar
calculateHours();
}

function count_hours(cal_id, event_name){
var hours = 0;
var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(cal_id);
var this_year = new Date(2013,0,1);
var now = new Date()
var events = cal.getEvents(this_year, now, {search: event_name});
for ( i = 0 ; i < events.length ; i++){
var event = events[i];
if ( event_name.toLowerCase() == event.getTitle().toLowerCase() ) {
//Logger.log(event.getTitle());
var start = event.getStartTime() ;
var end = event.getEndTime();
start = new Date(start);
end = new Date(end);
hours = hours + ( end - start ) / ( 1000 * 60 * 60 );
}
}
var cal_name = cal.getName();
// retorna el nombre del calendario y numero de horas del evento
return [cal_name, hours];
}

function hours_in_events(events){
var hours = 0;
for ( i = 0 ; i < events.length ; i++){
var event = events[i];
Logger.log(event.getTitle());
var start = event.getStartTime() ;
var end = event.getEndTime();
start = new Date(start);
end = new Date(end);
hours = hours + ( end - start ) / ( 1000 * 60 * 60 );
}
return hours;
}

function authorize() {
var oauthConfig = UrlFetchApp.addOAuthService("calendar");
var scope = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar";
oauthConfig.setConsumerKey("anonymous");
oauthConfig.setConsumerSecret("anonymous");
oauthConfig.setRequestTokenUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetRequestToken?scope="+scope);
oauthConfig.setAuthorizationUrl("https://accounts.google.com/OAuthAuthorizeToken");
oauthConfig.setAccessTokenUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetAccessToken");
}

/*
* Count hours of events with same name
*/
function countHours(calId, eventName){
authorize();
var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calId);
var key = "...";
var query = encodeURIComponent(eventName);
calId = encodeURIComponent(calId);
var params = {
method: "get",
oAuthServiceName: "calendar",
oAuthUseToken: "always",
};
var url = "https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/"+
calId+"/events?q=" + query + "&key=" + key;
var request = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params);
var response = Utilities.jsonParse(request.getContentText());
//Logger.log(response);
var cal_name = response.summary;
var items = response.items;
var start, end;
var hours = 0;
for ( i = 0 ; i < items.length ; i++){
if ( items[i].status != "cancelled" ){
if ( items[i].summary == eventName ){
start = items[i].start.dateTime;
end = items[i].end.dateTime;
start = new Date(start.replace(/-/g,'/').replace(/[A-Z]/,' ').substr(0,19) );
end = new Date(end.replace(/-/g,'/').replace(/[A-Z]/,' ').substr(0,19));
hours = hours + ( end - start ) / ( 1000 * 60 * 60 );
}
}
}
// retorna el nombre del calendario y numero de horas del evento
return [cal_name, hours];
}

function calculateHours(){
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var id_cal_pos = 1;
var event_name_pos = 2;
var cal_name_pos = 1;
var total_hours_pos = 4;
var s = ss.getSheets()[0];
var rows = s.getDataRange();
var nRows = rows.getNumRows();
var values = rows.getValues();
// from second row
for ( var i = 1; i < nRows ; i ++){
var row = values[i];
var cal_hours = count_hours(row[id_cal_pos], row[event_name_pos]);
var h = cal_hours[1];
var cal_name = cal_hours[0];
s.getRange(i+1, cal_name_pos).setValue(cal_name);
s.getRange(i+1, total_hours_pos).setValue(h);
}
}
```

Comment: And when that link no longer works?

Comment: @AlEverett nothing is forever. I preferred put the code in a github gist, because I make updates over the code.

Comment: this was very helpful in getting started -- thanks for the gist!  Just need to know that need to create a spreadsheet where Calendar ID is in B2 and Meeting name is in B3

Comment: I cannot get this to work, what would be the "correct" calendar ID? has it changed since this code was created?

Answer (score 6):

I wrote up [a script in Google Script](http://gist.github.com/paucoma/7b7b6cecddfa79d25531#file-gglcaleventsonspreadsheet-gs), which I would like to contribute in case it helps someone else stumbling across this question. I adapted some [code from the Google sample code on Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/calendar).

The script searches a specific calendar for events within a defined date range and sums up the hours and days that these events have been registered as. It fills the Sheet which is associated to this script with

- a summary of "Same Name" Events accumulated days and hours
- a list of each event that was captured with its associated start date, end time and durration in hours.

**Steps**

```
1. Go to your google Drive and start a new Empty SpreadSheet.
2. Go to the Menu: Tools --> Script Editor.
3. Copy+paste the code into the new Code.gs and Save the File
4. Go to the Menu: Resources --> Advanced Google Services
5. Scroll till you find the **Calendar API** and turn it **ON** --> Click OK
6. Modify the gbl... vars to suit your interest.
7. Go to the Menu --> Run --> RunMe
8. An Authorization request will popup, (only the first time you run it)
  8a. Click Review Permissions
  8b. Select your google account, click continue
  8c. It will say "This App isn't verified", click Advanced, then Goto <project name> (unsafe)
  8d. It will tell you which permissions are required, Click Allow
9. If all went well you should be able to return to the Sheet and see the results.  
10. For easy Access from the sheet add the function within the Menu: Tools -- > Macros --> Import

---- Functions ----
Run --> RunMe : Runs Using the Defined Range
Run --> RunLast24h : Runs using the last 24h as date range
Run --> RunToday : events from Today
Run --> RunYesterday: events from Yesterday
```

Here is the link to the script: http://gist.github.com/paucoma/7b7b6cecddfa79d25531#file-gglcaleventsonspreadsheet-gs

Comment: Took a little massaging to get it to do exactly what I want, but this is working for me.

Comment: @MBraedley Glad it worked out for you, If you find the time, comment on the Gist what mods/massages you required to get it working to your needs to be able to improve it for the next person.

Comment: I've put it in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/MBraedley/bf9985034d759755c1f0e6b40ef14862).  I created a calendar just to track which days I'm in the office, and which days I'm working from home, so I don't really care about hours, just days or fractions thereof, so I added some more logic to tabulate the totals for the various events (right now those being "Home", "Office", and "Vacation", although I'll probably be adding "Work Travel" as well).

Answer (score 2):

Based on my need for, i discovered you're question.

Later on i found a cute solution : [GTimeReport](https://www.gtimereport.com)

Comment: If you affiliated with the product please disclose this in your answer and explain *how* the product solves the problem.

Comment: Although this answer could have been answered much more in detail, etc... IT HELPED ME OUT greatly! Terrific little tool. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A very nice google calender sidebar (free) gadget. It sums the activities according to tags that you write in the event description.

http://www.theproductivitygame.com/TimeTracker

Tags can be created in the task description in the form:

tags: tagName1, tagName2, etc.

where tagName is the tag/label name that you want to summarise by

Comment: This gadget is no longer available (I'm the author).

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the total amount of hours spent on a certain event (filtered by name) and visualize it on a graph with [CalendarDash](https://calendardash.com). There you will be able to plot your total time spent (per event name) on a bar chart, given a date range. You'll also be able to plot the same data on a line chart and do some more advanced filtering (you can, for instance, have each data point displayed on the graph being the summation of your weekly hours per event name, as requested in the original post). As far as I know, that is the only solution available that works reliably and does not require messing with scripts and/or spreadsheets (other than the free and open-source https://google-calendar-hours.com, which is a simpler app without all the fancy data visualization and filtering available on CalendarDash). Disclaimer: I am the developer of the latter - it is a free/non-commercial data visualization project which was started due to my disappointment with the available alternatives and time tracking apps in general.